# What should i do now?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

i'm a student cybercrime.

I've tested sql injection on an indian site that sells properties etc..

I was vunerable so i kept going with testing.

so after half an hour i managed to get all the usersnames and passwords also the admin username and password + adminpage.

What should i do now? just leave it or report it to the organisation?

i'm a bit afraid that they will be angry that i did this you know.

I really want to report it but its just i don't want to get troubles or so

EDIT : i did nothing to the site or database, i just looked in the database

Thanks

Comment: If you're a cybercrime student you should be well aware that "just looking" doesn't make it legal. That said, we have already plenty of questions here regarding different ways of disclosure.

Comment: You managed to create an anonymous StackExchange Account so why don't you just create a anonymous email address or something and then tell the company about the vulnerability. Most companys want to know how secure their products are. Some even offer monetary reward for this

Comment: but please note that this question is off-topic

Comment: See if they have a responsible disclosure policy. I'm not sure on the law in your country but without prior permission, it is normally illegal to attack a website so they may pursue legal action. I would contact them and ask how to report a security issue, judge their response   and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have accessed a network infrastructure that was not your own and you did so without the written permission of the company/corporation nor that of the ISP.  You have committed the felonious act of a gray hat hacker. However, if you are truly concerned for the stability of the company site and infrastructure you could as another user has suggested, create a bogus e-mail and perhaps use the tor browser to communicate your concerns.There are sources out there that demonstrate how to setup your own testing lab(s).